# Why "No data available in table" message display when even data available in the table

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, datatables

I have created a data table which data coming from fire-base database. It display all the data perfectly but "No data available in table" message is display top of the table body.Why is that?. When I click "ascending and descending buttons or search box" table become empty.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td  class="th">Title</td>
        <td  class="th">First Name</td>
        <td  class="th">Last Name</td>
        <td  class="th">Hospital</td>
        <td  class="th">Spciality</td>
        <td  class="th">Doctor Fee</td>
        <td  class="th">Mobile Number</td>
        <td  class="th">Address</td> 

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table> 

[![<script type="text/javascript">
 var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("User/doctor");

  rootRef.on("child_added",snap =>{
  var fname=snap.child("Firstname").val();
  var lname=snap.child("Lastname").val();
  var id=snap.child("DoctorID").val();
  var dob=snap.child("DOB").val();
  var address=snap.child("Doctor_Address").val();
  var email=snap.child("E-mail").val();
  var mobile=snap.child("Mobile_no").val();
  var hometp=snap.child("Home_no").val();
  var sex=snap.child("Sex").val();
  var hospital=snap.child("Hospital").val();
  var slmcno=snap.child("SLMC_Number").val();
  var speciality=snap.child("Spciality").val();
  var emargancyperson=snap.child("Emargency_person").val();
  var emargancyrelationship=snap.child("Emargency_reletionship").val();
  var emargancymobile=snap.child("Emargency_TP").val();
  var fee=snap.child("Doctor_fee").val();
  var nic=snap.child("NICNo").val();
  var title=snap.child("Title").val();

  //var lname=snap.child("DocotID").val();

  $("#example").append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+fname+"</td><td>"+lname+"</td><td>"+hospital+"</td><td>"+speciality+"</td><td>"+"Rs."+fee+".00"+"</td><td>"+mobile+"</td><td>"+address+"</td></tr>");

 });
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: \[
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        \]
    } );
</script>][1]][1]
```

[image: this is the data table]

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything in this code that even tries to remove or hide it.  (Nor is there anything shown that adds it, which suggests you've left some relevant code out of the question....)

Comment: @DanielBeck That is from the [`datatables`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) jQuery plugin.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that.  Looks like data tables expects you to use its [.row.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) method rather than just appending table rows on your own?  Also you're appending rows directly to the table instead of to the `tbody`, that may be part of the problem as well.

Comment: @DanielBeck, you nailed it, this should be an answer

Comment: @DanielBeck Yep, I was typing up an explanation for @Kalpa, but that is correct. He should be using `.row.add()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Firebase, but it looks like the function below is a method that fetches data from your db, then adds it your table on the front end.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("User/doctor");

rootRef.on("child_added",snap =>{
  var fname=snap.child("Firstname").val();
  ...
  $("#example").append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+fname+"</td><td>"+lname+"</td><td>"+hospital+"</td><td>"+speciality+"</td><td>"+"Rs."+fee+".00"+"</td><td>"+mobile+"</td><td>"+address+"</td></tr>");

});
```

If my assumption is correct, then I think your problem is probably that you are not using datatables correctly. Connecting to a DB takes time, so you probably initialize the table before the data is fully fetched from your DB. So what is happening is that your table initializes with no data, then you add the data to the table. Because you are manually adding the data through jQuery, the table doesn't know to hide the no data message, which is a component of the plugin.

When you say you sort or search and get an empty table, you are probably seeing a side effect of the above scenario, where the table has data, but the **datatables** doesn't know about it because you never added it to datatables.

You will need to either **initialize the table after the data is added** to the HTML, or **initialize the table before the DB fetch** and use datatables api to update the datatable.

I typically do the second one, so in that case, you would just need to move the table initialization to before your DB fetch, then change the jquery to a datatable api call.

```js
var datatable = $('#example').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'\
  ]
});

var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("User/doctor");

rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

  var fname = snap.child("Firstname").val();
  //Other columns here

  var data = {
    "nfname": nfname
  };
  datatable.row.add(data)

});
```